# How do I parse json array object with Angular.js?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, api, yammer

I am consuming a Yammer RESTful API with AngularJS. I have been able to get the yammer user.json api to work but need guidance consuming and displaying the yammer messages.json api. If anybody could help with the scope syntax, that would be cool.

Parse json to return messages > body > rich
Here is the code:

Controller

```
function YammerGetUserCtrl($scope, $http ) {  
 $http.get('https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}}).  
      success(function(data) {  
       $scope.users = data;  
      console.log($scope.users)  
     });  
 }
```

JSON

```
    {
        "threaded_extended": {},
        "messages": [
            {
                "id": 654897910,
                "sender_id": 1506696042,
                "replied_to_id": null,
                "created_at": "2016/02/12 20:55:02 +0000",
                "network_id": 11319,
                "message_type": "update",
                "sender_type": "user",
                "url": "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/654897910",
                "web_url": "https://www.yammer.com/arrow.com/messages/654897910",
                "body": {
                    "urls": [
                        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yueP7V6Wddc&index=7&list=PLKsggbHA8DermEtbMcC80M38cuR5rFdgi"
                    ],
                    "parsed": "Our shiny new aerospace [[tag:8909387]] that ran in Colorado markets during Super Bowl 50 is going viral! In less than one week since broadcast, we have more than 414,000 views on YouTube, increasing by thousands an hour. The [[tag:8898375]] has caught media attention around the world in the UK, Ireland, Australia, Germany and more. Even mention by MIT Media Lab.\n\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yueP7V6Wddc&index=7&list=PLKsggbHA8DermEtbMcC80M38cuR5rFdgi",
                    "plain": "Our shiny new aerospace #ad that ran in Colorado markets during Super Bowl 50 is going viral! In less than one week since broadcast, we have more than 414,000 views on YouTube, increasing by thousands an hour. The #video has caught media attention around the world in the UK, Ireland, Australia, Germany and more. Even mention by MIT Media Lab.\n\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yueP7V6Wddc&index=7&list=PLKsggbHA8DermEtbMcC80M38cuR5rFdgi",
                    "rich": "Our shiny new aerospace <span class='yammer-object' data-yammer-object='tag:8909387' data-resource-id='8909387' data-resource-model='tag'>#<a href='https://www.yammer.com/arrow.com/topics/11782336'>ad</a></span> that ran in Colorado markets during Super Bowl 50 is going viral! In less than one week since broadcast, we have more than 414,000 views on YouTube, increasing by thousands an hour. The <span class='yammer-object' data-yammer-object='tag:8898375' data-resource-id='8898375' data-resource-model='tag'>#<a href='https://www.yammer.com/arrow.com/topics/8400514'>video</a></span> has caught media attention around the world in the UK, Ireland, Australia, Germany and more. Even mention by MIT Media Lab.<br><br><a class=\"linkified\" href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yueP7V6Wddc&amp;index=7&amp;list=PLKsggbHA8DermEtbMcC80M38cuR5rFdgi\" title=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yueP7V6Wddc&amp;index=7&amp;list=PLKsggbHA8DermEtbMcC80M38cuR5rFdgi\" target=\"_blank\"
            .....
    }
```

So I would like to display the url and rich excerpt from the body. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Edit, here is the AngularJS solution.

```
$http.get("your_data").success(function (data) 
{ 
   $scope.users = data.messages; 
   console.log("users" , $scope.users); 
});
```

and in HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" > 
   <div>Rich: {{user.body.rich}}</div> 
    <div>URL: {{user.url}}</div> 
</div>
```

To directly access the `rich` property, you can use this code:  `user.messages[0].body["rich"]`. Similar goes for `url` Explanation: messages has an array with one element, and the object `body` which has the property `rich`. See below my results after debugging in the console.     [image: Console view of the JSON]

Comment: iulia , Excellent. Thank you so much. I will try it now. Let you know in a few....

Comment: Well, I believe that is working, I see the json response but I think my htnl code is wrong. I tried  <td> {{ user.messages}}</td>   <td> {{ user.messages.body.rich}}</td> <td> {{ user.rich}}</td>... any advise? Thank you

Comment: Hi, yes, here is my idea in AngularJS form:     `$http.get("your_data").success(function (data) {
      $scope.users = data.messages;
      console.log("users" , $scope.users);
  });`  
and in HTML     `<div ng-repeat="user in users" >              
      <div>Rich: {{user.body.rich}}</div>
      <div>URL: {{user.url}}</div>
  </div>`  Of course, you may style however you want in the HTML.

Comment: You rock!  It's always a little like x-mas when one's code works and is displayed....Thanks Santa!

Comment: You're welcome, ho ho ho.  I will edit my initial answer to add the AngularJS solution. Remember that when you found the solution to your question, best is to accept an answer so that the question doesn"t remain open.   PS: [Dilemma of the programmer](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A6PSWTFCUAI7N-5.jpg)